# When did the first electronic body modifications take place?

Tags: cultural-history

I have recently been reading about a variety of body modifications ranging from a simple tattoo or ear ring. This led me to wondering about the history of body modification. I tried to ask this as a broad question, but it was too broad, so this led me to wondering when the first body modification involving electronics took place.

**When did the first electronic body modification take place? What was it?**

Comment: Easily pre-historic around the globe, because numerous stone-age cultures discovered in the 18th and 19th century practiced, including the Maori and Polynesians.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens How do you think I could make this more specific? A specific type of body modification?

Comment: It may not be possible - as the answer to so many variations is *clearly pre-historic*. The onus really is on you to inquire about a specific body modification that can be proven to NOT be pre-historic, and there may not be any that have ever been widely practiced.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens What about the way I phrased it now? Still to broad?

Comment: You could argue hearing aids. The first optical modifications came about because of Sir Isaac Newton ("glasses")...we've come a long way since however with entire forearms including hands being recreated, sight reconstruction, pacemakers, etc...

Comment: Possibly the earliest (1803) post-mortem electronic body modification: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giovanni_Aldini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guy. 2004, added an antenna.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_Harbisson

It vibrates based on electromagnetic transmissions just for the hell of it.

Now the first useful cyborg? Doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Surely you can add content beyond "fill fill fill"? could you summarize the link, tell us what the antenna did, whether it was successful?  Something?

Comment: Maybe you could add some more detail.